# how to setup cluster environment on same machine websphere 7.0 for session management

Tags: session, cluster-computing, websphere-7

I was trying to set up a cluster in IBM WAS 7.0 my question is : How can I set it up that when i bring node01 down my session is taken care by node02.

Here is what i did: 
i had a network deployment with a deployment manager and a server node01. I deployed my ear file on node01 and started the server and it was working. i stopped the application and did not uninstall it.

then I added a node02 through profile management. But there was no cluster. so I created a cluster from console and added the node01 and then added node02 from profile management. then started the cluster.

NOW! on both the servers the systemOut.log files i see they get started up and the application also starts up. I goto my application URL

http://localhost:9081/finAppWeb/login.do and i get the application and i log in. I see in systemOut.log I am logging in to the node01 server. Then I goto the other systemout.log and the app is started there as well but ofcourse no login messages as I logged into node01@9081 and my node02 is on port 9082.

As I am logged in I close the node01 webspehere server (not the node/nodeagent)  and 9081 goes offline. Then i go into the 9082 and just enter a URL that comes after the login : http://localhost:9082/finAppWeb/main.do and it says that i have a session that is expired. I was assuming that when i goto 9082 I woudl be logged in automatically as they session will exist on all nodes through WAS deplyment manager and my session would be managed by that?

How can I set it up that when i bring node01 down my session is taken care by node02 and I get redirected to 9082 or when i hit 9082 it shows my logged in user. is that possible. if not then what is session management for fail over or high availability.

Thanks
Syed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work, you need to set up HTTP session replication (and to make sure that all attributes stored in the session are serializable so that they can be replicated).

Comment: Thanks for teh replyin my application all the session objects are serializable. but how do i setup HTTP session replication?